# how to use regular expression for validation of String must begin with letter, all other characters can be letter/number/space in java

Tags: java, regex

I am doing validation of String which contains ASAHSHAS,342746726,GHG55656 this valid String and spaces are allowed.
Thanks In advance!!

Comment: You said it **must** begin with letter, how can 342746726 be valid?

Comment: @adarshr I think he means that the entire thing is a string (including the commas). At least that's what I think he means.

Comment: @adarshr you are correct i am wrong that string must start with letters only

Comment: @adarshr, it appears that the OP is just trying to ask the same question again, instead of improving the original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314777/need-a-code-using-regular-expression-in-java-string-must-be-captial-lettersa

Comment: @jzd - Yes indeed you're right! I too got the same doubt but didn't bother to verify. Voting to close now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Comment: Am I the only one that worries that a-zA-Z may not match all letters? It's Unicode, so what about Greek, Cyrillic, and other alphabets (see http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/Blocks-3.txt).

Comment: it's just contain A-Z and 0-9 and spaces and must start with letter

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression that you are looking for may look like this `^\\w[\\w\\d ,]*$`. This is an example using it:

```
String string = "ASAHSHAS,342746726,GHG55656";
if (string.matches("^\\w[\\w\\d ,]*$")) {
    System.out.println("It matches!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("It does NOT match!");
}
```

Comment: \w includes _.  That may or may not be a letter for the OP